# vuejs кастом директива с директивами в нутри

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как можно в кастом директиве через innerHTML задать хтмл с другими директивами или интерполяцией:

```
    Vue.directive('error', {
        bind: function (el, binding) {
            el.innerHTML = '<div class="errorFormContainer brand-danger" v-show="serverError != null" v-text="serverError"></div>';
```

Получется сейчас директива работает, а директивы у дива не отрабатувают.

Comment: А ты пробовал компилированную версию писать через [render](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) ? тогда можно и html передавать и как slot ) так работает быстрее и вообще можно много чего накрутить :) :) :) только нужно не забывать что сборка проходит снизу вверх

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается через создание компонента:

```
 Vue.component('err', {
        template: '<div>{{errMsg}}</div>',
        methods:{ ...
```

Затем :

```
<err></err>
```